# Internal links in a Mosaico template?

Tags: mosaico

Using CiviCRM 4.7.22.

My customer wants to have internal links in the newsletter template. They could do this in the 'old' CiviMail editor using the flag symbol.

It is not obvious to me if the same functionality is available in Mosaico and if so, how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

By "internal links" do you mean anchor links? A link that would go to another spot in the email? If this is the case, it might be answered here: [How can I set up anchors in Mosaico mailing?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/23052/how-can-i-set-up-anchors-in-mosaico-mailing)

Comment: Concur that in wysiwyg they use a Flag for the Anchor feature