# How can I set up anchors in Mosaico mailing?

Tags: mailing, mosaico

I am trying to set up anchors in my MOSAICO mailing so that at the top of the mailing I can have links to headers further down.
Any advice welcome? 
(P.s. not a programmer, so please keep it lay!)

Answer (score 5):

looks like there is no way to do this via the limited 'what you see is what you get' (WYSIWYG) editor, so this would have to be done in the code of the block you are working in, by clicking onto the source button < > And then using the html for an anchor link.

For example your first anchor link can be called 'one'

You would use it as follows. If you had a list of heading points at the top of the email as such.

1) My heading one

2) My heading two

3) My heading three

Then you would put the anchor in like this:

```
<ol>
    <li>
        <a href="#one">My first heading</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#two">My second heading</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#three">my third heading</a></li>
</ol>

<a name="one">1) </a><p>My section one here</p>
<a name="two">2) </a><p>My section two here</p>
<a name="three">1) </a><p>My section three here</p>
```

Comment: Just a wee point. Sadly, html anchors have very patchy implementation in email clients. So it might be worth thinking through who you want to receive your emails - if your recipients will be using diverse devices and email clients then anchors may not work for everyone. For eg, see: https://knowledge.hubspot.com/articles/kcs_article/cos-pages-editor/how-can-i-add-an-anchor-link-in-my-email-or-page

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it looks like anchors doesn't work in Mosaico with CiviCRM v5.3.2 with that code above.  You get a error message even after clearing your browser's cache:
This page isn’t working
[civicrm site] redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

And yes, using email anchors is iffy in general and rethinking the design of the email may be best option (even though anchors may be cool to use).

Comment: although, hypothetically if you turn tracking for mass emails, it may work. BUT most folks want the metrics