# can't create anchor links in Mosaico -- it strips internal anchor tags?

Tags: mosaico

I'm trying to use anchor links in Mosaico mails. (Yes I know they aren't universally supported in mail clients, but using them wasn't my decision :-)

According to [this post](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/23052/how-can-i-set-up-anchors-in-mosaico-mailing) this should be possible, entering the `<a name="">` tag manually in code edit view. There are [other posts discussing bugfixes for tracking issues](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/31507/using-internal-anchor-links-in-mosaico-emails) with anchor links, so I thought they would be supported.

But it seems my Mosaico editor is stripping the `<a name="">` tag (it disappears when saving).

I've not found a Civicrm config setting that addresses this...I assume it must be configurable in Mosaico? But I'm also having trouble finding Mosaico documentation that discusses this.

Comment: Update: I've found the Mosaico documentation talking about templating, but I'm really hoping there's a simpler way to address this!

Comment: If it's useful info -- seems we're using the standard versafix-1 template.

Comment: Which version of CiviCRM and which version of Mosaico?

Comment: Drupal 9.5.3, CiviCRM 5.58.1, Mosaico 2.11.1676403645

Comment: I'm not seeing that behaviour on the same setup, except Drupal 7 (which I don't think should make a difference). Maybe try it on dmaster.demo.civicrm.org and see if you have the same problem there?

Comment: Tested it on dmaster.demo.civicrm.org, sure enough, it works fine -- but that is with the latest Mosaico extension version 3.1.1687383640.  I guess I need to get our admin to upgrade the Mosaico extension?

Comment: I guess next step is to can set up another test environment with the older version and confirm that an upgrade solves the problem. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: Aaaaand I've tested on several other systems and also never saw this behavior, even with the older version.  Went back to the original system and it now seems to be working. A real head-scratcher, but for now I won't look a gift horse in the mouth.

Comment: @minbori just a quick word of caution, the upgrade to the latest Mosaico may not be complex to implement, but might cause incompatibilities with older templates. With that being said, I really enjoy the spacing options on the new Mosaico and the ability to copy paste more than plain text.