# Using internal anchor links in Mosaico emails

Tags: mosaico, flexmailer

Even though anchor links don't work in all mail clients, we have still been using them in emails for tables of content in a monthly newsletter. It seems like at least a few others have run into the same problem we have, which is that Mosaico breaks anchor links:

[How can I set up anchors in Mosaico mailing?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/23052/how-can-i-set-up-anchors-in-mosaico-mailing)
[Internal links in a Mosaico template?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/21048/internal-links-in-a-mosaico-template)

I've found that the issue is actually because Flexmailer seems to try to apply tracking to all URLs, including anchor links, which breaks them. I've put those details here:

https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.flexmailer/issues/43

Does anyone have ideas how this could be fixed simply?

Comment: Is this still an issue? There were PRs around tracking links in Sept 2019.

Comment: Fixed last year: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/20115

Answer (score 1):

Adding an answer for completeness' sake:

This was a bug and it was fixed last year in the following commit https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/20115

So if you update your Mosaico extension, it should be fine.

Credit: [@LarsSG](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/31507/using-internal-anchor-links-in-mosaico-emails?noredirect=1#comment50884_31507)